# Not able to get value from the Kendo Combobox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using below code in Kendo Grid editor but unable to access value of selected item value from Combobox.

Moreover, I have done same thing in Kendo drop down list but unable to kendo Combobox, so if anyone has solution please let me know.

Thanks in Advance !

```
{
                    field: "SalesBookId",
                    title: "Sales Book",
                    template: "#= (typeof SalesBookId != 'undefined') ? GetSalesBookName(SalesBookId):'' #",
                    editor: function (container, options) {

                        $('<input required data-text-field="SalesBookName" data-value-field="SalesBookId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoComboBox({
                                autoBind: false,
                                dataSource: dsSalesBookDropDown,

                            });
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown the `dsSalesBookDropDown`, nor `GetSalesBookName` so it is hard to know what is wrong in your specific case.

This [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/ufoRoLAS) demonstrates that when the configurations, handlers and data all align properly there should not be a problem.

The dojo is a based on the example "Grid with local data", your *SalesBook* concept is changed to *Seller* for the example.

Code related to the custom editor include

```
var sellers = [
  { SellerId: 1, Name: "Andrew" },
  { SellerId: 2, Name: "Basil" },
  { SellerId: 3, Name: "Chuck" },
  { SellerId: 4, Name: "Dennis" },
  { SellerId: 5, Name: "Edward" }
  ];

var dsSellersDropDown = sellers;    

function GetSellerName (id) {
  var seller = sellers.find(function(x) {return x.SellerId == id });
  return (seller) ? seller.Name : "** invalid id " + id + " **";
}

var products = [{
    ProductID : 1,
    ProductName : "Chai",
SellerId: 1,
    SupplierID : 1,
    CategoryID : 1,
. . .
```

grid config

```
                        dataSource: {
                            data: products,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductName: { type: "string" },
SellerId: { type: "number" },
```

and

```
                        columns: [
                            "ProductName",
{ field: "SellerId",
  title: "Seller Name",
  template: "#= (typeof SellerId != 'undefined') ? GetSellerName(SellerId):'' #",
  editor: function (container, options) {

    $('<input required data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="SellerId" data-bind="value:' 
+
options.field
+ '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoComboBox({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: dsSellersDropDown,
     });
  }
},
                        { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
```

Comment: I have resolved my issue with help of you response. I just added schema into my grid and working fine. You're so helpful.